# How to assign unique external IP addresses to each domain virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, centos

My hosting provider gave me bunch of external IP addresses and its internal IP addresses assigned to each external IP.

I was able to assign Main IP address and the second one but rest of them does not seem to work properly as I cannot get them to show the correct site. When I assign one of the site using the third or fourth IP address then when I try to access the domain via browser, it loads another site that had been assigned via main IP address instead.

Given that one of the site in the same server is showing is a good sign as the external IP address is in fact pointing to the correct server but it seems though httpd.conf and the other conf file in conf.d that is getting included are set up wrongly.

The setup I've got is...

```
<VirtualHost [Internal IP Address]:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/directory
ServerName domain.com.au
ServerAlias www.domain.com.au
etc....
</VirtualHost>
```

The main thing is that, it's working for only two domains and I've got `NameVirtualHost` and `Listen` set up for all of the IP internal addresses under `httpd.conf`

Is there something that I'm missing?